# Bin Deploy MVC 2.0 site to IIS6 with .Net 3.5 SP1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, iis-6

I've built an ASP.Net MVC 2.0 site in VS2010, targeting .Net 3.5.
I'm trying to 'bin deploy' to a server running IIS 6.0.

The server is a 'test' virtual server running Windows Server 2003 R2 64bit, and .Net 2.5 SP1.
MVC has not been installed on this server.

I am trying to replicate the hosting environment where this application will be deployed for production.

The issue I'm having is every page I try to browse to shows a 404.
I've tried adding .mvc and .aspx to the routes in the Global.asax.cs file, but it seems to make no difference.

I've also created a Default.aspx page which redirects to the Home.aspx (or Home.mvc) URL.
Nothing seems to work.

I've been browsing the web for hours searching for an answer, and still nothing works.

Any ideas?

**Edit**

Wow, I feel like a right idiot now... :) Turns out that ASP.Net wasn't registered properly so the ASP.Net v2 extensions were still disabled on the IIS6 server.
I guess small things like this get past when you've only worked with Server 2008 and IIS7 for the last year or 2...

So I'll mark this as 'Answered / closed'...

Comment: Just answer your own question and then mark as the correct answer. This means the question won't lurk around looking unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that ASP.Net wasn't registered properly so the ASP.Net v2 extensions were still disabled on the IIS6 server. I guess small things like this get past when you've only worked with Server 2008 and IIS7 for the last year or 2...